# dplyr summarise multiple variables based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I would like to summarise data as `mean` and `sd`, or `median` and lower and upper quartile, depending on if they are normally distributed or not.

Using `mtcars` as an example, this is how I am doing one variable at a time:

```
sum= mtcars%>%
group_by(am)%>%
summarise(MPG = paste0(mean(qsec), " (", sd(sec), ")")
```

I'd like to do something like this

```
norm = c("qsec", "drat", "hp", "mpg")

sum= mtcars%>%
group_by(am)%>%
summarise(across(where(. %in% norm), . = paste0(mean(.,na.rm = T), " (", sd(.,na.rm=T) , ")") )
            )
```

and add the relevant line for median and quartiles.
Would also be happy with a `for` loop solution and then ? `rbind`.

Comment: May I ask what you mean with "depending on if they are normally distributed or not"? Do you want to test the distributions?

Comment: Thinks @Quinten. No, I have already plotted and tested the distributions of each variable. I'm just using a random(ish) selection in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to do something like this:

```r
library("dplyr")

norm <- c("qsec", "drat", "hp", "mpg")

my_summary <- mtcars |>
  group_by(am) |>
  summarise(
    across(
      all_of(norm),
      ~ paste0(mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), "(sd=", sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE), ")")
    ),
    across(
      !all_of(norm),
      ~ paste0(median(.x, na.rm = TRUE), "(", quantile(.x, 1/4), " - ", quantile(.x, 3/4), ")")
    )
  )
```

You can simply use `all_of` to select the columns you want from `norm` or negate it.